# Oracle compressed index - How to determine which columns to compress

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have the following index that I would like to create for an Oracle applications table.

```
create index xxhr_api_transactions_idx1 on hr.hr_api_transactions (status, process_name, nvl(selected_person_id, -1)) compress 3
```

The table has 62421 total rows. 10 distinct values in the status column. 23 distinct values in the `process_name` column. 17419 distinct values in the `selected_person_id` column. Only 43530 values exist for the `selected_person_id` column, the rest are null (new hire workflows where the person does not exist yet).

My query would be something like:

```
select *
from   hr.hr_api_transactions psth   
where  psth.process_name in ('TFG_HR_NEW_HIRE_PLACE_JSP_PRC', 'HR_NEW_HIRE_PLACE_JSP_PRC', 'HR_NEWHIRE_JSP_PRC')   -- TFG specific.
--and    nvl(psth.selected_person_id, -1) in (:p_person_id, -1)   -- 1118634
and    psth.status not in ('W', 'S')   -- Work in Progress, Saved For Later.
```

My question is should I use compress 3 or compress 2? Is it better to compress the `selected_person_id` column with its 17419 distinct values out of 62421 total (and what about the 18891 nulls) or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compression claims and advice are notoriously bad.  This is one of those tasks you truly need to test for yourself.  You can test the compression by checking `DBA_SEGMENTS.BYTES`.

Compression is a trade-off between CPU and size.  In my experience, basic index compression has a very tiny CPU overhead.  As long as the size is more than a few percent smaller I'd recommend using the increased compression settings.

Use the below code to test the segment size of no compression up to `compress 3`.  Make sure you test with a sufficiently large amount of data.  Oracle allocates space in extents; if you use a small test size you'll only be measuring the extent size overhead.

```
drop index hr.xxhr_api_transactions_idx1;
create index xxhr_api_transactions_idx1 on hr.hr_api_transactions (status, process_name, nvl(selected_person_id, -1));
select bytes/1024/1024/1024 gb from dba_segments where segment_name = 'XXHR_API_TRANSACTIONS_IDX1';

drop index hr.xxhr_api_transactions_idx1;
create index xxhr_api_transactions_idx1 on hr.hr_api_transactions (status, process_name, nvl(selected_person_id, -1)) compress 1;
select bytes/1024/1024/1024 gb from dba_segments where segment_name = 'XXHR_API_TRANSACTIONS_IDX1';

drop index hr.xxhr_api_transactions_idx1;
create index xxhr_api_transactions_idx1 on hr.hr_api_transactions (status, process_name, nvl(selected_person_id, -1)) compress 2;
select bytes/1024/1024/1024 gb from dba_segments where segment_name = 'XXHR_API_TRANSACTIONS_IDX1';

drop index hr.xxhr_api_transactions_idx1;
create index xxhr_api_transactions_idx1 on hr.hr_api_transactions (status, process_name, nvl(selected_person_id, -1)) compress 3;
select bytes/1024/1024/1024 gb from dba_segments where segment_name = 'XXHR_API_TRANSACTIONS_IDX1';
```